How to organize a synthetic organic laboratory workbook?
After a few years of working in organic synthesis, I've come to realise the importance of a well organised laboratory notebook. Despite getting better at it, I still struggle to maintain a consistent format for each reaction.
Similarly, I always struggle to name my compounds from different projects in a logical manner. So if anyone has a naming system that works well I am all take!
Scientists are constantly under pressure to obtain results. Hence, there are number of times where I rush reactions that seem easy (99% yield reported), miss important details and end up with shocking yields. On the other hand, there are times where I drop down every single little detail, closely follow the reaction (TLC, MALDI + ASPCI, NMR) before realising that most of it was unnecessary and therefore a waste of time.
There are also certain things that one should record during routine reactions for publication down the line. For example, I initially did not know carbon NMR of all non-published structures were mandatory (seems very obvious now).
I have recently moved onto an electronic notebook as it allows to have all information on one page (NMR, Mass, TLC photos). With multiple written lab notebook, re-reading the 10 similar reactions done over a year, comparing the NMR's , the TLC's, the mass spectra etc was really not convenient and definitely made me repeat a lot of mistakes. There is however a chance that electronic notebooks may not be readable by someone that may need it in 15 years' time.
I am well aware that each synthetic chemists works differently and that labs are different etc. However, I am curious on whether there are people out there with more experience that I have which would like to share tips, good practices or even examples of well written, well-structured notebooks which make life easier. I am open to anything that could be useful!

Hmm, this is likely to get closed here, but maybe on Academia.SE... It's opinion-based, somewhat unclear and too broad. Also there's not even a precise tag for it!

If your academic lab is not a regulated lab e.g., you are not filing patents or doing legal work, then you can create your own synthesis procedure templates in a Word file before you start an experiment with your advisor's consent. Since organic chemists have to plan the synthesis before hand, it is easy to type up the experimental steps with missing information. For example, mass of reagent, volumne of solvent, actual bath temperature, stirring time etc.

(contd...)So most of the text will be written and you can fill in the missing as you conduct the experiment and the procrastination to describe the procedural details won't set in. Look up how Organic Synthesis beautifully describe the methods in a reproducible way. (www.orgsyn.org)

Is the question eventually about manually written ones, or electronic/ELNs? One for daily work, an other which only has the reaction equation, scale and isolated yield about the first time a reaction was run with a time stamp and cross reference to the original lab journal for additional details. Individual and yet recognizable labels per reaction, i.e., XYZ-12345 by Mr XYZ to mark e.g., by XYZ-12345-2 the 2nd fraction of chromatography, The CCC as a reminder & organizer what still has to be done is more useful on a computer, though.

@Buttonwood Thank you!

@TheRedManJolanBonelli It still is not clear if the lab book in question is bound paper version/manually written, or an electronic one (both have their pros and cons). Re TLC you mention to record a photo. Every image processing can introduce some color error depending on camera and light source used (white balance, color temperature), a photo can introduce an error of scale/dimension. In one previous group, the PI bought a few affordable desktop MFC printers: after derivatization, the Xerox of the cooled Al sheets eventually were stapled into the book (no sand in the books & colorful enough).
